# Path lifting in principal bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Let $\pi : P \rightarrow M$ be a principal $G$-bundle and let $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow M$ be a smooth path. I define a lifting of $\gamma$ on $P$ in the following way: if $\{U_\alpha\}_\alpha$ is a trivializing open covering of $M$ I can find a partition $\{t_i\}_{i = 0}^k$ of $[0,1]$ in such a way that $\gamma([t_{i - 1},t_i]) \subset U_{\alpha_i}$ for each $i$. Now I can define the lifting of $\gamma$ as $\tau(s) := (\sigma_{\alpha_i} \circ \gamma)(s) \cdot g_i$ for $s \in [t_{i-1},t_i]$ where $\sigma_{\alpha_i} : U_{\alpha_i} \rightarrow P$ is a smooth local section and $g_i \in G$ is used to adjust the starting point of each segment. Now I want to prove that the path $\tau : [0,1] \rightarrow P$ is smooth but I am not sure how to prove the smoothness at the points $\{t_i\}_{i = 1}^{k - 1}$ (at the endpoints is obviously smooth).

Comment: Do you have a reason to expect this construction to give a smooth path...? For a principal $\mathbf{R}$ bundle over an interval, what prevents the trivializing sections from making the lift piecewise-linear with arbitrary slopes?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang $\tau$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and smooth on each subinterval $[t_{i-1},t_i]$. I hope that it is smooth also globally. I have found this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362286/path-lifting-property-induced-by-local-triviality-of-a-principle-g-bundle?r=SearchResults, but does not say anything about the partition points

Comment: As @AndrewD.Hwang has mentioned, you haven't given any conditions to ensure the lift will be smooth at the points $t_i$. For example, if you were taking the horizontal lift with respect to a connection, the fact that $\tau'(t_i)$ must lie in the horizontal direction would ensure the smoothness of the overall path. But you have no such condition. So in general, no your lifted path will not be smooth.

Comment: @user17945 I want to prove the existence and uniqueness of horizontal lifting, in  Kobayashi and Nomizu’s book just start from a general smooth lifting $\tau$ amd then write the horizontal lifting $\gamma’(t) = \tau(t) \cdot g(t)$ for a smooth path $g :[0,1] \rightarrow G$. I am realizing that the smoothness in not assured, what condition should I give to ensure the smoothness at the points $t_i$?

Comment: You didn't mention in your original question that you were constructing the *horizontal* lift, and without this information one can't assure the lift is smooth. However as I mentioned in my previous comment, the fact that the lift is horizontal is enough to ensure smoothness. This is because by virtue of the fact that $\gamma'(t_i) \in H_{\gamma(t_i)}$ (in your now-changed notation), it means that the one-sided derivatives of $\gamma:[t_{i-1},t_i]\to P$ and $\gamma:[t_i, t_{i+1}]\to P$ at $t_i$ will agree, which will ensure smoothness of the overall path $\gamma$.

Comment: @user17945 Oh sorry for the bad notation $\gamma’$ is the horizontal lift of $\gamma$ not the derivative. $\tau$ insted is a generic lift of $\gamma$

Comment: @user17945 At the end I don’t need the smoothness of $\tau$ to prove the smoothness of the horizontal lift of $\gamma$ at the points $t_i$

Comment: @Fra I see. Let's call the horizontal lift $\gamma^h$ instead. Then my comment should be corrected to read "$(\gamma^h)'(t_i) \in H_{\gamma^h(t_i)}$", where I use $(\gamma^h)'$ to denote the derivative of $\gamma^h$.

Comment: IIRC, to take a horizontal lift you have to equip the principal bundle with a connection, which is extra structure; as stated you can't prove the lift is smooth, because under the conditions in the question the lift need not _be_ smooth. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I now understand that the path I defined is not smooth at the points $t_i$, thank you both very much:)